gpg unusable secret key
gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long

shows:
sec   rsa2048/588EFF3348F037FB 2013-04-25 [SCEA]
...
uid                 [ultimate] ...

But if I try to sign a file with that key, I get:
skipped "588EFF3348F037FB": Unusable secret key

What is the problem here?

Is the key expired?

@Kusalananda it's set to never expire
